# PrimeNG textarea issue with not working spacebar

Tags: primeng

I met a problem:

I use Angular with PrimeNG GUI.
I created table with p-table and populate domain objects.
I can edit cells and rows but I can only write, I can't use spacebar into table's textarea and inputtext.
I have no idea yet, maybe  have somebody faced such problem?

```html
<p-table 
[value]="th.repository.getAll()" dataKey="id" 
selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="th.selectedEntity" editMode="row" 
[tableStyle]="{'min-width': '300px'}" styleClass="p-datatable-gridline" styleClass="p-datatable-striped"
(onRowSelect)="th.onRowSelect($event)"
(onRowUnselect)="th.onRowUnselect()"
[paginator]="true"
[rows]="10"

>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
       <th colspan="3" >
        {{"Final goods".toString().toUpperCase()}}
        <p-button (click)="th.onAddRaw()" class="tableButton"  label="Добавить" [outlined]="true" severity="secondary"></p-button>
       <p-button (click)="th.onDeleteRaw($event)" class="tableButton" label="Удалить" [outlined]="true" severity="secondary"></p-button>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:60%">Name</th>
            <th style="width:30%">HS CODE</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Edit</th>

        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-concreteFinalgoods let-editing="editing" let-ri="rowIndex">
        <tr [pEditableRow]="concreteFinalgoods" [pSelectableRow]="concreteFinalgoods">

            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="30" pInputTextarea [autoResize]="true" [(ngModel)]="concreteFinalgoods.name"  class="fullWidth"></textarea>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{concreteFinalgoods.name}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="30" pInputTextarea [autoResize]="true" [(ngModel)]="concreteFinalgoods.tnved" required class="fullWidth"></textarea>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{concreteFinalgoods.tnved}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>

   <td>
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-2">

        <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton pRipple type="button"
         pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" (click)="th.onRowEditInit(concreteFinalgoods, ri)" 
         class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"></button>

        <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button"
         pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" (click)="th.onRowEditSave(concreteFinalgoods, ri)"
          class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success mr-2"></button>

        <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" 
        pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" (click)="th.onRowEditCancel(concreteFinalgoods, ri)" 
        class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-danger"></button> 

    </div>
</td>

        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class Repository{
  
    private entities!:Entity[];
    private url:string="";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getEntitiesObservable(): Observable<Entity[]> {
       return this.sendRequest<Entity[]>("GET", this.url+"?all");
    }

    init(url:string){
        this.url=url;
        this.getEntitiesObservable().subscribe(data => this.entities = data);
    }
    getAll():Entity[] {
        return this.entities;
    }
    

    private sendRequest<T>(verb: string, url: string, body?: Entity)
        : Observable<T> {

            console.log("Repository -sendRequest----\n"+verb+"\n"+url+"\n"+"object sent from angular:\n"+JSON.stringify(body));

        let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        let out:Observable<T> = this.http.request<T>(verb, url, {
            body: body,
            headers: myHeaders 
        }).pipe(catchError((error: Response) => {
            throw(`Network Error: ${error.statusText} (${error.status})`)
        })); 

        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: I too have had this issue, I cannot assume that each time someone types a character that they want a space after. Wish there was another answer. This happened to me after I updated Angular and PrimeNG to their current latest versions (I think 17 for both).

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know why it is issue arose, but I made a little trick for solve

```js
  onKeyDownEvent(event: any){ 
        event.target.value=event.target.value+" "; 
}
```

```html
 <textarea  (keydown.space)="th.onKeyDownEvent($event)"   rows="3" cols="30" pInputTextarea [autoResize]="true" [(ngModel)]="concreteFinalgoods.name"  class="fullWidth"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running into the same issue I had. There are several mentions of this across different versions of Prime* products. They are using Datatables under the hood and it seems to have issues when combining certain features. In your case and mine, it was the combination of `selectionMode="single"` in the `p-table` and the corresponding `pSelectableRow` property on the `<tr>` element. It seems you cannot (without workarounds like the previous answer) use both **Row Selection** and **Editable Cell/Row**. Once I removed the row selection, my editable cell worked perfectly again!